# Increment value by one every 7 rows - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I m trying to increment a date by one day every 7 rows (week). if have use the below formula which provide the desirable output nut on looking for a better solution. any suggestions?

`=IFERROR(IF(OFFSET(A4,-1,0)=OFFSET(A4,-7,0),OFFSET(A4,-1,0)+1,OFFSET(A4,-1,0)),OFFSET(A4,-1,0))`

[image]

Comment: Use the `ROW` formula. Something like `INT(ROW(RC)-ROW(R2C))/7)` (or use `A1` notation which I hate).

Comment: If you start in A1, in A2 and down `=IF(MOD(ROW(),8)=0,A1+1,A1)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You could try in `A2`:

```
=$A$1+INT(ROW(1:1)/7)
```

Answer (score 2):

Cell A1: 01/01/2019

Cell A2 (and similarly onward): = IF(MOD(ROW(A2); 7) = 0; A1+1; A1)

Comment: Your formula is almost correct apart from the first date (it is being changed after 6 instead of 7 rows). I think you simply need to adjust your `MOD(ROW(A2); 7)` to `ROW(A1)` to make it work. Apart from that, nice work.

Answer (score 2):

Silly solution but it also works... simply add 1/7th of a day with each row increment:

Cell A2:

```
=A1+1/7
```

Result (changed formatting to hh:mm for clarity):

[image]

Comment: @JvdV edit - I see your logic and I was worried for a minute that a formula is incorrect; but it looks like it works as long as the first date starts at midnight (00:00). See my edited post & the screenshot (hope I'm not going crazy!)

Comment: Simple, simpler, simplest! +1

Comment: Just beware that it's not an easy `VALUE` to calculate with on further calculations (might that be neccessary), since it's not an integer number ;)

Comment: Please note: **this suffers from floating-point rounding errors.** The first error occurs after 29 days and then quite regularly. By my calculations when the above calculation should hit `2019/01/05` it actually has the value of `43469.9999999999` - which if you use `INT(CELL)` to get the base day would return the wrong day. It's never a good idea to repeatedly add fractions together.

Comment: @JvdV - It's simple, but it's faulty. In this case it is too simple.

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity, thanks for your comment. I also was worried about the rounding errors but I tested the formula for the next few years ahead (end of 2022) and it still looks fine. Please see the screenshot -> [link](https://i.imgur.com/c2VaoWJ.png) column A is my formula, column B is the date using `=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))` and then standard COUNTIF in column C `=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10228,B2)`. The filter shows that the only count is number `7`. I'd be happy to see your analysis and understand where the issue is. Cheers

Comment: @JustynaMK - Excel rounds the date up when it formats the `43469.9999999999` so it appears to be right date, but most formulas would interpret the date as a fraction of a second before midnight on the previous day.

Comment: @JustynaMK - If you put `=int(RC[-1])` in the second column (using `R1C1)` mode then you'll see some of the dates are now wrong in the second column.

Comment: @Enigmativity ahh I see what you're saying, thanks for explaining. On 6th of January there will be a difference between `INT` formula, which will return `43470`, versus my formula, which displays `43471` but is actually `43470.999999999900000000`. It's hard to say what OP intends to do with this data set but I guess as long as s/he uses different methods of working with dates (`DATE` formula, changing column's format to Date) then my solution will also work (and is potentially faster). But thanks for the feedback, it's good to know what are the drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[image]

Of course, in the crazy `A1` notation it looks like this: `=A$1+INT((ROW()-ROW(A$1))/7)`.

To avoid division entirely you could use this:

```
=A1+IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW(A$1),7)=0,1,0)
=R[-1]C+IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW(R1C),7)=0,1,0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you let me know how to increment date time once every 1000 rows in excel? Considering the date and time format is DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS

Comment: Change the `7` to `1000`. The date format doesn't matter. You are just formatting the cell. It does not change the underlying number.